# OpenLDAP TLS config - cannot set TLS - invalid credential

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

Hi I was googling to find out why my attempt to change a config of open ldap for TLS failed on access right:

```
root@labm:~/slapd# more /root/slapd/tls.ldif
dn: cn=config,dc=LDAPTEST,dc=NET
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/key.pem
-
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/cert.pem


ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin,dc=LDAPTEST,dc=NET" -W -f /root/slapd/tls.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

Failed because obviously I used admin to change config entry. I found an article about the same issue, and the solution there was to set a root password for the config database and then try to modify it. So I created a hash for my mypassword and stored it in changepwd.ldif:

```
slappasswd -h {SSHA} -s <mypassword>

vi /root/slapd/changepwd.ldif

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}av9lfvBlCwBBETzHxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Succesfully modified the config olcRootPW (and I checked it in /etc/ldap/slap.d/cn=config/ files)

```
ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -D 'cn=config' -f /root/slapd/changepwd.ldif
```

But again when I try to change TLS settings with `cn=config` and the new mypassword, the attempt fails on invalid credentials:

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=config,dc=LDAPTEST,dc=NET" -W -f /root/slapd/tls.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: <mypassword>
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

The content of the config file is:

```
 cat /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{0\}config.ldif
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 175b5eb1
dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: a965b54a-7586-1036-95d8-ad7092a067bf
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20170123070944Z
olcRootPW:: e1NTSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
entryCSN: 20170124144811.769576Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20170124144811Z
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

```
sudo ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -f /root/slapd/tls.ldif
```

(note the `sudo`).

The access condition in your config db:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
```

means access to config db is allowed to users authenticating with `EXTERNAL` method if uidNumber and gidNumber is zero (that is: it is root).

`EXTERNAL` auth is this case means you access the directory throught a pipe on the filesystem (the ldapi:/// scheme) and the operating system does authentication/authorization based on your user.

That's why you need to be root.

Please also note the `dn` of the tls.ldif file has to be changed to:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
[...]
# same as before
```

The `cn=config` is a root namespace and it is not a leaf namespace of your data namespace.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation, you suggestion worked, I have sucesfully changed the TLS properties.